# Can you help identify seal markings?

Tags: meaning, seal

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have over 40 ink paintings that I am trying to identify, flowers, fish, humans, horse etc. They are painted on very thin paper with Chinese writing.

Comment: There are affordable stamp and calligraphy script identification services (印章和书法文字识别) on Taobao, such as [this one](https://www.taobao.com/list/item/597960939027.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the correct answers but I can give you a little correct information about these figures.

1. The first one contains a fish, which has a certain meaning. If you hope to know the meaning of the fish, you should read or display the Chinese characters in it clearly. These Chinese characters will five you very correct information about this figure.
2. The second image shows an animal that may not exist in real life, but whose main characteristics are derived from real-life animals, one of which is turtle. It's apparently a combination of a turtle and an aquatic creature. The large front half is a turtle, and the small back half is from another aquatic creature, such as a fish. But the texture on the turtle's back should be basically symmetrical. Obviously, the lines on the right half of the turtle's back are normal, but there are two characters on the left. Only experts who study oracle bone inscriptions can tell you which two characters they are. I guess they are the name of a person in ancient Chinese mythology. If we figure out what these two characters are, we can basically guess why the author drew this picture like this.
3. The third picture is two seals, which can be the name of a person or an organizationw by oracle bone inscriptions, or Xiaozhuan. In short, the characters above are definitely not in the current Chinese font. If you recognize the words inside, all the meanings will be understood.

I hope this information helps you. If you want to thoroughly understand the meaning of these pictures and texts, the key is to recognize the words in them.